# How to provide map with a comparator that requires static data?

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I am trying to provide a map with a comparator that requires static data.  However, the following approach fails because (my compiler tells me) C++ doesn't accept static constructors:

```
struct MyOrder {
    static std::map<std::string, int> m_specialOrder;
    static MyOrder() {
        m_specialOrder["First"] = 1;
        m_specialOrder["Second"] = 2;
        m_specialOrder["Third"] = 3;
    }
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator x = m_specialOrder.find(a);
        if(x == m_specialOrder.end()) return false;
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator y = m_specialOrder.find(b);
        if(y == m_specialOrder.end() || x->second < y->second) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

I want something like static construction because I only need one instance of the m_specialOrder map and I don't want it initializing every time I use the comparator or define a map that uses it.

My goal is to be able to use my special ordering on a map like:

```
std::map<std::string, double, MyOrder> mySpecialMap;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you making your constructor static?

Comment: I hope you're not thinking of changing the static data in the comparison function while the map is active. Changing the order of the keys in a map will break the map badly.

Comment: As the error implies, a `static` constructor has no meaning in C++.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: No, don't want to change the static data.  I just want to prevent the data from being reinstantiated with each use of the struct.  Added a paragraph to the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++98 you can do it like this:

Put this in your header file:

```
static std::map<std::string, int> m_specialOrder;
static std::map<std::string, int> initSpecialOrder();
```

Put this in your cpp file:

```
std::map<std::string, int> MyOrder::m_specialOrder =
    MyOrder::initSpecialOrder();

std::map<std::string, int> MyOrder::initSpecialOrder() {
    std::map<std::string, int> res;
    res["First"] = 1;
    res["Second"] = 2;
    res["Third"] = 3;
    return res;
}
```

In C++11 and up you can remove `initiSpecialOrder`, and use curly braces initializer instead:

```
std::map<std::string, int> MyOrder::m_specialOrder = {
    {"First", 1}, {"Second", 2}, {"Third", 3}
};
```

Comment: Alternatively you can define the init function locally in the source file (static or nameless namespace)

Comment: Wait, so the initSpecialOrder() needs to return a std::map<std::string, int>, right?  And the call to initSpecialOrder needs to occur in the execution path sometime after the start of main() and before the comparator is used, right?

Comment: @feetwet "Yes" on the first part, "no" on the second. Indeed, `initSpecialOrder` needs to return `std::map<string,int>` which is now fixed. However, you do not need to make this call anywhere. C++ compiler will make it for you, because it is part of the initializer `std::map<std::string, int> MyOrder::m_specialOrder = MyOrder::initSpecialOrder();` All you need to do is placing it anywhere in one of the C++ files.

Comment: Ah ha -- that appears to work (or at least compile)!  It looks like we either need to return m_specialOrder from the initSpecialOrder call, or if it works as a void function declare it as such?

Comment: @feetwet Oops, that was another copy/paste error. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `static` constructor -- it makes no sense, simply use:

```
 MyOrder() {
    m_specialOrder["First"] = 1;
    m_specialOrder["Second"] = 2;
    m_specialOrder["Third"] = 3;
}
```

Comment: Since `m_specialOrder` is static, you would end up running this code more often than you should.